# BackboneJS How to add <comparator>-method to model

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have made a Model which I made to display the whole discography of a band which I get delivered by an API as JSON. So far so good, but I need to sort the albums by its releasedate, so I intent to use the `comparator`-method, which is not possible to use on Models. So I want to "transform" the Model into a Collection, or is there maybe a better way?

Here is my model I define on my discography.js:

```
ArtistDiscography.ArtistDiscographyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return App.APIO + '/i/artist/' + this.get('slug') + '/releases';
    },      
    parse: function(response){
        return response.data;
    },
});
```

the `slug` value is the JSON value, which returns for example `rihanna`. The JSON file also contains a value called `releaseDate`.

In my maincontroller.js, I have this:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var ArtistDiscographyModule = require('modules/discography');
)};

ArtistController.prototype.initDiscography = function(name) {
    this.artistdiscographyModel = new ArtistDiscographyModule.ArtistDiscographyModel({slug: name});
    this.artistdiscographyModel.fetch();
    this.artistdiscographyModel.on('sync', function() {
        this.artistDiscographyView = new ArtistDiscographyModule.View({model: this.artistdiscographyModel});
        App.useLayout('artistDiscography', 'artistDiscography').setViews({
            '.releasesDiv' : this.artistDiscographyView,
        }).render();
    }, this);
};
```

The JSON response is:

```
data: [{
  "slug" : "rihanna",
  "releases": {
        "title" : "Music Of The Sun",
        "releaseDate": "2005-08-29",
        "tracks": [{ //array of tracks}]
  }, {
       "title" : "Pon de Replay",
       "releaseDate": "2005-08-22"
       "tracks" : [{ //array of tracks}]
  }
}]
```

Can someone help me out? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you please paste the json response?

Comment: @Marc there you go, check the code above, added the JSON response :-)

Comment: i think you have to use Collection instead array as releases property

Comment: I tried to use Collection, but it fails at `this.get('slug')` - how can I do that with Collection? `this.collection.get('slug')` doesnt work and doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

You can set collection as an attribute of model:

```
ArtistDiscography.ArtistDiscographyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        slug: '',
        releases: new Releases()
    }
});

Releases = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Release
});

Release = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: '',
        releaseDate: '',
        tracks: []
    }
});
```

Then you can add comparator into `Releases` collection.

Or you can go dirty and use the [underscore's sort](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) function for array:

```
_.sortBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return Math.sin(num); });
=> [5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: This would also be my suggestion. Split the Response in different models makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along these lines?....

```
ArtistDiscographyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ArtistDiscography.ArtistDiscographyModel,
    comparator: function (model) {
        return (model.get('releases').releaseDate);
    }
});
```